# $5$ "identical" dice?

Tags: combinatorics, dice

*Question in video*:

> $5$ identical dice are thrown simultaneously. How many different outcomes are possible?

*Solution in video*:

> Here, we are **not** given **different** dice, but **same** dice. So, the outcomes from the dice can't be rearranged.
> Then the video proceeds with cases from: $0,1,2\dots5$ different outcomes and solved it.

**My question**:

> In my understanding, if we can read the number of the dice then we can definitely identify/distinguish them and rearrange them. Though when same number appears on more than $1$ dice then the dice with same numbers can't be distinguished. So, I can't really digest the solution given by the video.

Basically what is the difference between different dice and identical dice (in real world?)?
Please help.

Comment: which video...?

Comment: @Beautifullyirrational Lecture video

Comment: This is just semantics.  You are free to consider the ordered set of rolls (distinguishing the dice however you like) or, as appears to have been done here, you are free to consider unordered rolls.  Both of these are good counting problems.

Comment: @lulu whoever whenever came up with this problem must have imagined/created such "identical" dices. I want to know/see them. Right now I only know I dice and I may call it identical or different.

Comment: As you are aware, they just look like dice, which they are. The point is that you are being directed to ignore the ordering of the outcomes. Both ordered and unordered selections arise in real world, so it's good to learn counting methods for both cases.

Comment: @lulu read the comment below gandalf61's answer.

Comment: But why does the solution emphasise that "the outcomes from the dice can't be rearranged"? Are they considering the relative positions of the (indistinguishable) dice, so the orders in the outcomes matter?

Comment: @peterwhy no for "identical" dice the order doesn't matter but it does for "different/distinguishable" dice.

Comment: So I was wondering why the solution mentions "the dice can't be rearranged". If the dice really can't be rearranged, then "12344" would be different from "23441".

Comment: @peterwhy language perhaps does look confusing. But "can't re-arrange" here means that "12344" and "23441" are same for us, so we can't rearrange former to look like latter as we already have it, by looking from some other direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With identical dice we are counting combinations - the order of the list of outcomes for each dice does not matter because we cannot assign an outcome to a specific dice. With different dice we are counting permutations - the order of the list of outcomes does matter, because we can assign each outcome to a specific dice.

For example, there is only 1 way to throw 1,2,3,4,5 with five identical dice, but if the dice are different (each has a different colour, for example) then there are 120 ways to throw 1,2,3,4,5.

Comment: Well, I hoped to learn something new (and mind-blowing) but if just meant different colour vs same colour dice then I'm bummed. (Not on your answer, but who ever chose to call them different and identical dices instead of different coloured and same coloured dices). Anyways, thanks a lot, reduced the entropy of mind. Upvoted.

Comment: @InanimateBeing I only gave colour as an example. Could be different sizes, or different weights, or have different markings on their faces - basically, anything that let's you tell one dice from another.

Comment: Yes, I forethought that much @gandalf61. But no surprise. What I'm surprised at is how shallow the water was than what I was considering several metres deep. My mistake. Thank again for such a lucid explanation.

Answer (score 3):

Let $x_i$ be the number of dice that land on $i$.  Then you want to know how many solutions there are in non-negative integers to $x_1+x_2+x_3+x_4+x_5+x_6=5$.  This is a classic stars-and-bars problem, and the answer is $\binom{10}{5}=252$.

The point of considering the dice to be identical (instead of, say, different colors) is that the only thing that distinguishes two throws is how many different dice give you each result, not which specific dice give you that result.

Comment: +1 : Great answer.  I completely agree that your analysis is better than the analysis in my answer.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. +1. It helped.

Answer (score 1):

Addendum added to respond to the comment/question of
InanimateBeing.

---

Because the $(5)$ dice are presumed identical, the problem becomes **more** rather than less complicated.

You have to consider how the dice rolls may be *grouped*, and provide a count, for each grouping.  Case work shown below.  For each Case, I will use $T_k$ to denote the enumeration for Case $k$.

---

$\underline{\text{Case 1: all 5 dice the same number}}$ 
There are $\displaystyle ~\binom{6}{1}~$ ways of determining which element from $\{1,2,3,4,5,6\}$ will be shown. So,

$$T_1 = 6.$$

---

$\underline{\text{Case 2: 4 of one number, 1 of another  number}}$ 
There are $\displaystyle (6 \times 5)$ ways of choosing the number that will show $(4)$ times and then choosing the number that will show $(1)$ time.

$$T_2 = 30.$$

---

$\underline{\text{Case 3: 3 of one number, 2 of another  number}}$ 
There are $\displaystyle (6 \times 5)$ ways of choosing the number that will show $(3)$ times and then choosing the number that will show $(2)$ times.

$$T_3 = 30.$$

---

$\underline{\text{Case 4: 3 of one number, 1 of another  number, 1 of a third number}}$ 
There are $\displaystyle \left[6 \times \binom{5}{2} \right]$ ways of choosing the number that will show $(3)$ times and then choosing the two numbers that will each show $(1)$ times.

$$T_4 = 60.$$

---

$\underline{\text{Case 5: 2 of one number, 2 of another  number, 1 of a third number}}$ 
There are $\displaystyle \left[\binom{6}{2} \times 4 \right]$ ways of choosing the two numbers that will each show $(2)$ times and then choosing the number that will show $(1)$ time.

$$T_5 = 60.$$

---

$\underline{\text{Case 6: 2 of one number, 1 of another  number, 1 of a third number, 1 of a 4th number}}$ 
There are $\displaystyle \left[6 \times \binom{5}{3} \right]$ ways of choosing the number that will show $(2)$ times and then choosing the three numbers that will each show $(1)$ time.

$$T_6 = 60.$$

---

$\underline{\text{Case 7: 5 different numbers show}}$ 
There are $\displaystyle (6)$ ways of choosing the number that does not show.

$$T_7 = 6.$$

---

$\underline{\text{Final Computation}}$

$$T_1 + \cdots + T_7 = 6 + 30 + 30 + 60 + 60 + 60 + 6 = 252.$$

---

**Addendum** 
Responding to the comment/question of InanimateBeing.

> ... my question has more to do with the dice than the combinations.

Suppose that the $5$ dice are all different colors, so that (for example) having the $(5)$ different numbers of 1-2-3-4-5 can occur in $(5!)$ ways.

Then, the number of possibilities for each of the $(5)$ dice is **totally independent** of the possibilities for any of the other dice.  This is a consequence of the dice being different colors.

In this situation, the enumeration would therefore be

$$(6)^5.$$

---

**Addendum-2**
I thought that it was somewhat coincidental, that the enumeration turned out to be $~\displaystyle \binom{10}{5}.~$  See my comment, following the answer of Robert Shore, which uses Stars and Bars analysis.

For pertinent references, see

- [this article](https://brilliant.org/wiki/integer-equations-star-and-bars/)
- and [this article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics)).

Comment: Thanks a lot for your hearty efforts. Upvoted. But my question has more to do with the dice than the combinations.

Comment: Treat it as a stars-and-bars problem, as in my answer, and it’s much simpler.

Comment: @InanimateBeing See the Addendum that I have just added to the end of my answer.

Comment: @InanimateBeing I know that it's not coincidental.  I was describing my thought process, as I initially composed my answer.  Given that the answer turned out to be $~\binom{10}{5},~$ I suspected that there was a more elegant approach that I hadn't thought of.  See my comment to the answer of Robert Shore.

Comment: Then it's alright. It's just that the wording brings out a slightly different meaning so I was saying that. Thank you for the links.